# How to restrict or hide fedex shipping method based on conditions at checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, shipping-methods, fedex

How to hide or restrict the FedEx calculation in the checkout page

I don't want to show the FedEx shipping method based on product attribute value at the checkout page?

For example

1. The attribute code "shipping_applicable_for_fedex"
2. If the attribute set as no, I don't want to show the FedEx shipping method on the checkout page
3. If the attribute is set as yes, I want to show the FedEx shipping method on the checkout page

Can anyone please guide me to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How to hide or restrict the FedEx calculation in the checkout page

I don't want to show the FedEx shipping method based on product attribute value at the checkout page?

```
The attribute code "is_test"
If the attribute set as no, I don't want to show the FedEx shipping method on the checkout page
If the attribute is set as yes, I want to show the FedEx shipping method on the checkout page
```

Can anyone please guide me to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.

```
<?php

namespace Podsix\Tweaks\Model;

use Podsix\Tweaks\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $dataHelper;
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $productFactory;

    
    public function __construct(
        Data $dataHelper,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $showHazmatInfo = false;
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
            if($product->getIsHazmat()) {
                $showHazmatInfo = true;
            }
        }
        $hazmatBlock = $this->dataHelper->getBlockByIdentifier('hazardous_shipping_notice');
        $hazmatBlock_ups = $this->dataHelper->getBlockByIdentifier('hazardous_shipping_notice_ups');
        if($showHazmatInfo && $hazmatBlock->getIsActive()) {
            return [
                'is_hazmat_block' => $hazmatBlock_ups->getContent()
            ];
        }else{
            
        return [
                'is_hazmat_block' => $hazmatBlock->getContent()
            ];  
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```